# Impossible to set a PlanningScene

Tags: ros, planning-scene, arm-navigation, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I'm trying to call the **"environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff"** service to get a *PlanningScene* to perform some collision checking. However, after a couple of days trying and searching in ROS Answers and more I didn't get any advance. My situation is the same that jbarry describes in [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/12147/did-not-get-reply-from-planning-scene-client-when-using-collisionmodelsinterface/) but this solution doesn't work in my case, I continue getting this:

```
[ WARN] [1345114122.403491890, 1345114122.395468950]: Incomplete robot state in setPlanningScene
[ERROR] [1345114122.403650694, 1345114122.395468950]: Setting planning scene state to NULL
```

I tried to debug manually searching through the different classes involved as Adolfo Rodriguez suggest in [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/40632/moving-custom-robot-arm-to-pose-goal/?comment=41547#comment-41547) (**collision_models.cpp**, **collision_models_interfaces.cpp**, **model_utils.cpp**) but I didn't find anything special except that if I print the joint_names.size() I get 13 joints (I expected 7). I also observed that when I launch the service I get 0 joints and the interactive markers in the RViz stops working.

I have also checked as bit-pirate suggest that **/joint_state** are correctly published (/world_joint and the 7 joints of my arm).

Can you say me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41564/impossible-to-set-a-planningscene/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-16**:
The problem seems different from the question you linked. The request looks like it's malformed. Can you say, where you are getting the different joint name/position sizes? You do set them correctly?

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-08-16**:
Hi dornhege. As I saw in all the other cases, the request is only a empty arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff:Request. I don't understand why I have to set it. I was obtaining the different joint name/position sizes when I put a ROS_ERROR to debug after the 44 line in the model_utils.cpp. Thx!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-16**:
OK, that should definitely work. An empty diff is a common use case.

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-08-16**:
Indeed, in all examples is sent an empty message and it works. So, do you have any idea where can be the error? I tried to generate the arm_navigation package with the wizard for different robots and I obtained the same result. Thanks.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-08-31**:
i'm stuck with the same problem, "incomplete robot state"...have you solved this problem yet?

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-09-02**:
No, I reviewed and tested again the code after 2 weeks and the result is the same: "incomplete robot state". Can help us @dornhege?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After days of work, now i can answer this question.

1. put the line above your main:

   static const std::string SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME = "/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff";
2. put the code below in appropriate position within your main.

   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   planning_environment::CollisionModels* collisionModels;
   planning_models::KinematicState* kinematicState;
   collisionModels = new planning_environment::CollisionModels("robot_description");
   kinematicState = new planning_models::KinematicState(collisionModels->getKinematicModel());
   ros::ServiceClient set_planning_scene_diff_client;
   while(!ros::service::waitForService(SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME, ros::Duration(1.0)))
   {
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("Waiting for planning scene service " << SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);
   }
   set_planning_scene_diff_client = nh.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff> (SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);
   arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff::Request planning_scene_req;
   arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff::Response planning_scene_res;
   //THE LINE BELOW IS VERY IMPORTANT!
   planning_environment::convertKinematicStateToRobotState(*kinematicState, ros::Time::now(), collisionModels->getWorldFrameId(), planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state);
   if(!set_planning_scene_diff_client.call(planning_scene_req, planning_scene_res))
   {
   ROS_WARN("Can't get planning scene");
   exit(-1);
   }
   else
   {
   ROS_INFO("Successfully get planning scene!");
   }
   collisionModels->revertPlanningScene(kinematicState);
   //must call revertPlanningScene() first before calling setPlanningScene(). otherwise you'll be blocked in setPlanningScene()
   collisionModels->setPlanningScene(planning_scene_res.planning_scene);

btw, you don't need to change other config files. just use the ones generated by the planning_description_configuration_wizard.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Your way doesn't set an empty planning scene, but provides a robot state.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-06**:
what's the difference between an empty planning scene and my method? in my trial, it doesn't affect the following operations, like FK, path planning, etc,  with my method.

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-09-06**:
Hi @yangyangcv, thanks for share the code, effectively, it works! However, when I try to get a complete state with "collision_models_->setPlanningScene(planning_scene_res.planning_scene)" don't works (it get blocked at this point). Do you tried it? I think that it can be related with @dornhege says.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-06**:
@mbj: i do get blocked in that call, don't know why. but i just edited my answer and added two lines at the buttom. now it works. but still i don't quite understand what's happening with the planning scene.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-06**:
in fact most of my above code are from planning_components_visualizer.cpp which is under the folder stacks/arm_navigation/src. the codes there are very clean and clear. so you can just refer that file.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-06**:
The difference is that it should work regardless, so there might still be something wrong somewhere else.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-06**:
@mbj: in the function setPlanningScene() which is in planning_environment/src/models/collision_models.cpp
i find this:
if(planning_scene_set_) {
ROS_WARN("Must revert before setting planning scene again");
return NULL;
}

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-06**:
so you need to call collisionModels->revertPlanningScene(kinematicState); before to call setPlanningScene()

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishing something called /world_joint is not what you need.  The Wizard by default produces a joint called /world_joint that reads in data from TF, transforming between the frame listed under the multi_dof_joints entry for world_joint as the parent_frame_id in your planning_description.yaml and the one listed as child_frame_id (which must be the root of your urdf).  This allows you to incorporate information from an odometric system.  Thus in addition to publishing /joint_states for your joints, you need to have a TF system running that publishes a transform from parent_frame_id to child_frame_id - this can just be an identity transform, but it needs to exist or the planning system will never fully initialize.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-03**:
thanks for the answer, but i'm still confused. in myRobot_planning_description.yaml, i have:  multi_dof_joints:

- name: world_joint
  type: Floating
  parent_frame_id: base_link
  child_frame_id: base_link   do i need to change the parent_frame_id?

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-03**:
and in another node publishing the joint state, i write:  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;  odom_trans.header.frame_id = "world_joint";     odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";  and then i set this transform to identity. is it correct?  by doing so, i still get the errors as above.

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2012-09-04**:
Change the odom_trans.header.frame_id to "base_link", and use a tf publisher to put it on the wire and things should work.

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-09-05**:
Thanks for your answers @egiljones, although these, I can't get running the PlanningScene. I didn't change anything in the config files, I only executed a tf_publisher "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 world_joint base_link 1" but the result is the same: "Incomplete robot state..."

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2012-09-05**:
If I change the frame_id to "base_link" as you suggested to @yangyangcv I get a TF_SELF_TRANSFORM error. I suppose that any change is necessary in the config file. Any idea? Thanks.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-05**:
thank god, i just got the whole thing running correctly! just wait a moment, i will post my solution.